# IOS HttpPost not working

Tags: ios

I am trying to send multiple parameter for a registration usage. Here is my Code for Posting data :

```
-(void)PostRegistrationData:(NSString *)userEmail :(NSString *)Password{

    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"username":@"something",
                             @"password":@"aFilter",
                             @"email":@"aCategory",
                             @"type":@"aCategory",
                             @"request_type":@"aCategory"
                             };

    /* We iterate the dictionary now
     and append each pair to an array
     formatted like <KEY>=<VALUE> */
    NSMutableArray *pairs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (NSString *key in params) {
        [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, params[key]]];
    }
    /* We finally join the pairs of our array
     using the '&' */
    NSString *requestParams = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];



    NSData *postData = [requestParams dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://teknofolk.com/spisrett_admin/slave/signup.php?"]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){
        // indicator.hidden = NO;
          NSMutableData *mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    }
}
```

But no data i getting inserted . Am i missing something?

Comment: What does "But no data i getting inserted" mean? Have you looked at what is being sent on the network with an analyzer such as Charles Proxy?

Comment: The code looks like it creates a get request, with the parameters like the go in the url with &'s between the pairs etc. Are you sure you create the proper request?

Comment: @Zaph Those are random data.There is no problem with the data.It should post data data to the url and url will get the data and insert on database.there is only one validation that all parameter should be sent.

Comment: @ophychius  the request params are ok. Here is what i am getting in the request param   type=1&password=aFilter&username=something&request_type=1&email=aCategory

Comment: Where are the delegate methods implemented? Just for testing try `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`.

Comment: Conventions are that method name and variable names begin with a lowercase letter and class names begin with an upper case letter. Further convention is that all method parameters be interspersed with the method name, that is parameters do not have bare ":" arguments. In this case the method declaration might be: `-(void)postRegistrationEmailAddress:(NSString *)emailAddress password:(NSString *)password`. Also don't name a string item data, that just adds confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have various choices what you want to use.

First option:

```
NSURLResponse *res = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *retData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&res error:&err];
```

(you have also the `async` way for this option).

or you can also follow your code and continue with this:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

and the request will be async and will call this methods (**you need that this view controller responds to the** `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse 
*)response
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

Comment: Zaph...thanks, but you can understand that is simple an error of copy and paste..before i was writing his method, than i wrote init..need just to add an `alloc` ;) done

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake in the parameter.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"username":@"something",
                         @"password":@"aFilter",
                         @"email":@"aCategory",
                         @"type":@"aCategory",
                         @"request_type":@"aCategory"
                         };
```

Worked with simply this :

```
                         @"type":@"1",
                         @"request_type":@"2"
                         };
```

In my insertion i was passing wrong value on type and request type. Thanks to all for all